# why my webproject in Java call already loaded external library for contained Applet

Tags: netbeans, applet, external, java

Hi i write web application which contains APplet and i use this tag to start my applet in Html page

```
<applet codebase="http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark" code="AppletBroadcaster.ZkusebniApplet" archive="AppletBroadcaster.jar, jave.jar " width="500" height="500"></applet>
```

I need use external library jave.jar in my applet so i added this file manualy into bulid/web folder of my Webproject. So all run fine. When a run my webproject java console write this

```
Basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Resource http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode for http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar
cache: Reading Signers from 1048 http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar | C:\Users\TTT\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\3\65f57583-24e73fd0.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar)
cache:  Read manifest for http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/jave.jar: read=1001 full=1001
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate hasnt been expired, no need to check timestamping info
security: Found jurisdiction list file
security: No need to checking trusted extension for this certificate
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: This OCSP End Entity validation is disabled
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment denied certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment session certificate store
security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
```

so it is obvious that jave.jar in my build/web folder was founded.

but when i push  in my applet the button for doing some operations from jave.jar, javaconsole writes this

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar with proxy=DIRECT
```

all what should jave.jar do is done correctly, but my question is why is so many times called lib/jave.jar when my jave.jar is in

```
http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark/
```

and was sucefully loaded during start of applet... What can i do for no call lib/jave.jar and why does it called? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The current applet element boils down to.

```
<applet
    codebase="http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark"
    code="AppletBroadcaster.ZkusebniApplet"
    archive="AppletBroadcaster.jar, jave.jar"
    width="500"
    height="500">
</applet>
```

This would make the JRE search for the Jar at `http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark` &  (failing that) any classes that are in it from the same path (or sub-directory according to package).  I suspect the `jave.jar` is actually another place, so the `archive` attribute should be more like:

```
<applet
    codebase="http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark"
    code="AppletBroadcaster.ZkusebniApplet"
    archive="AppletBroadcaster.jar, /path/to/jave.jar"
    width="500"
    height="500">
</applet>
```

Where `/path/to/` might be `/lib/` or other paths.

Comment: thanks for reply but i dont understand youentirely. I have not in my build/web folder any folders or packages like lib. And i didnt explicitly tell Java that she should search WebForSpark/lib/jave.jar but that my jave.jar is in root of web (CODEBASE) next to index.html. Only where is used lib folder is in my applet project but then in applets jar it isnt. My english isnt precise so please try to write me what you mean by anothers words..

Comment: Url is composed from CODEBASE + Archvive so in my case that is http://localhost:8084/WebForSpark + jave.jar  see my  first javaconsole log above from 9 row there is how JRE comunicates and downloads jave.jar. and YES I CAN ACCES JAVE.JAR FROM BROWSER, thats is new bad message for me ... i didnt perceive it, that is realy big security problem i must place my libraries on another place where user cant acces them via browser.... but where...

Comment: so i did some experiments. i tried create folder lib in myroot and put   jars in.  Add lib into codebase cause /WebForSpark/lib/lib/jave.jar so i tried set codebase back to only /WebForSpark and now it work well. but i dont realy understand why... my applet jar is copied to codebase and others jars are in lib folder and both are loaded sucessfuly.. in some connfigration file must be  writed that JRE must search jars in codebase/lib folder but where. and again- i can acces jars inlib folder trouhgt browser, where is safety place for jars?

Comment: so if my applet can use them thats means that all internet users can download jar only by typing url to browser? And i cant do that my applet can load external jars but internet users no ?

Comment: i am just reading your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205656/use-applet-in-netbeans-web-application  and now is clear for me thanks i will do some experiments tommorow.

Comment: Where do you add your aplet.jar? into lib folder too or into web folder with index.html ?

Comment: i ask you because when i added applet project to packing with my web project applet.jar is automaticly copied into folder with index.html in my case WebForSpark/web/applet.jar... If i create folder lib in application root and put there external jars and use codebase= "/lib" (like in your answer in second topic) then i have problem find my applet.jar becase is in web foder..

Comment: *"..in my case WebForSpark/web/applet.jar... "*  ***What?***  When did the `web` directory come into it, and what is `applet.jar`?  as to the path to those Jars.  Put them in the same directory if it is easier for you. If you do that: 1) Point the `codebase` to that directory. 2) List each Jar in the `archive` with no prefix.  (I don't know why this is so complicated for people!)

Comment: SOrry i confused you.  i thought build/web/AppletBroadcaster.jar file. And problem is that my IDE netbeans copy AppletBroadcaster.jar automaticaly into build/web/AppletBroadcaster.jar. It isnt adjustable in properties/packing option. That is bad in developing phase because when you something change in AppletBroadcaster pproject you must manualy copy new version of .jar into /lib folder in your web project... Is it true?